# Set "deny log on locally" in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

Using powershell in Server 2008 R2, how to set the Deny Log On Locally policy for my domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  You'd have to set this through Group Policy under `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment`

You *can* set registry-based GPO settings using the PowerShell cmdlet `Set-GPPrefRegistryValue` but the "Deny Log On Locally" GPO option doesn't appear to have a corresponding registry value to set.

Comment: I thought so as well, according to the official reference doc for server 2008 r2, it says there is no registry key for it.